# html and css positioning of html pages "elements"

Tags: html, css

i have question... iam writing simple html page with little bit of css.  EVERYTHING looks fine in IE, but if  I launch it with chrome - menu and My ContentPanel (iframe) are not abreast.

What shall i do?  i can use only HTML and CSS, something

small snippet of my css code:
1. button menu- 2O%

```
ul#buttonmenu{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 20%;
float: left;
}
```

iframe - as my second element on html page has width 80%.

```
iframe{
height:100%;
width:80%;
float: right;}
```

in IE it looks fine but in chrome not .... is there any gerenal rule how to fix it?

part of my html looks like:

```
 <div id="container" style="width:100%">

  <div id="header" style="background-color:#CDB4C8;",widht=100%>
<h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Name</h1></div>



  <ul id="buttonmenu">
  <li class="current"><a href="first.html" target = "content">first page</a></li>
  <li><a href="second.html" target="content">Second page</a></li>
  <li><a href="third.html"  target="content">Third page</a></li>
  <li><a href="fourth.html" target="content">Fourth page</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html" target="content">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>


 <iFrame id="content" name="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;float:left;">
  </div>
```

[Fiddle of this code](http://jsfiddle.net/nKPWV/)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? Show more of the code?

Comment: fiddle? which type of fiddle?

Comment: it's great that you create a jsfiddle so all of us can play with :)
jsfiddle.net

Comment: go to http://jsfiddle.net/, enter any HTML, CSS, or script code, hit save, and post the url here. Then we can all play with it and show you a full answer (it also helps us not have to type all the code over again)

Comment: I got it :) ive edited my question with html code - is it enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you shrink your width of your iframe width to 79% it's abreast.

```
iframe{
    height:100%;
    width:79%;
    float: right;
}
```

Alternatively you can just remove the border of the iframe and keep with width of 80%:

```
iframe {
    height:100%;
    width:80%;
    border: 0;
    float: right;
}
```

Example [jsfiddle with width: 79%](http://jsfiddle.net/nKPWV/1/) or Example [jsfiddle with border: 0](http://jsfiddle.net/nKPWV/2/)

Also on a side note I think you messed up on your code here:

```
<div id="header" style="background-color:#CDB4C8;",widht=100%>
```

I think you wanted to put:

```
<div id="header" style="background-color:#CDB4C8; width: 100%;">
```

Comment: I don't quite understand you question.  Are you asking if the code is for all browsers, or does it work in all browsers?

Comment: now it works. Maybe my question was bad or ... iam begginer in html and css ...  thanks for your advice

Comment: Checkout my update, see which solution you like better.  The border was causing the sizing issue in Chrome and FF.

Answer (score 0):

take out the border in the iframe and i did a float clear after it so the the container height is kept in case u forget :)

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
body{margin:0; padding:0;}

ul#buttonmenu{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 20%;
float: left;
}

#content{
height:100%;
width:80%;
float: right !important;
border:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width:100%">

<div id="header" style="background-color:#CDB4C8;",widht=100%>
<h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Name</h1></div>
<ul id="buttonmenu">
<li class="current"><a href="first.html" target = "content">first page</a></li>
<li><a href="second.html" target="content">Second page</a></li>
<li><a href="third.html"  target="content">Third page</a></li>
<li><a href="fourth.html" target="content">Fourth page</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html" target="content">Contact</a></li>
</ul>


<iFrame id="content" name="content" style="background-  color:#EEEEEE;float:left;">
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```